# How to update JFrame in another class?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to update an JLabel of created Control outside constructor or from another class. Here I created a Control and add some components in Constructor. The UI is created in main, but I want to update some label outside this class. So I create setResult(final String text, final String path) to do such a thing, but it is not working....

```
public class Control extends JFrame
{

private static Control control;
static HashMap<String, JLabel> results = new HashMap<String, JLabel>();
public Control(ArrayList<TestCase> tests)
{
    super("WFC Tests");
    setLayout(new GridLayout(tests.size() + 1, 6));

    start.addActionListener(bl);
    JComboBox comBox = new JComboBox(testCategoties);
    loopsField.setText("1");

    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    jp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    jp.add(comBox);
    jp.add(loops);
    jp.add(loopsField);
    jp.add(mainDevice);
    jp.add(mainDeviceText);
    jp.add(refDevice1);
    jp.add(refDeviceText1);
    jp.add(refDevice2);
    jp.add(refDeviceText2);
    jp.add(start);

    add(jp);

    for (TestCase test : tests)
    {
        add(createPane(test));
    }
}
private JPanel createPane(TestCase test)
{
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    test.getIterationTextField().setText("0");
    test.getCallTextField().setText("0");
    test.getHoldTextField().setText("0");

    jp.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    test.getTestCheckBox().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));
    jp.add(test.getTestCheckBox(), (int) JCheckBoxMenuItem.CENTER);

    jp.add(test.getLogCheckBox(), JCheckBoxMenuItem.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    jp.add(test.getIterationLabel());
    jp.add(test.getIterationTextField());

    if (test.getName().contains("Call"))
    {
        jp.add(test.getCallLabel());
        jp.add(test.getCallTextField());
    }

    if (test.getName().contains("Hold"))
    {
        jp.add(test.getHoldLabel());
        jp.add(test.getHoldTextField());
    }

    test.getResultLabel().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    test.getResultLabel().setOpaque(true);
    jp.add(test.getResultLabel(), JPanel.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
    results.put(test.getPath(), test.getResultLabel());
    return jp;
}
public static void run(final JFrame f, final int width, final int height)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            f.setTitle(f.getClass().getSimpleName());
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setSize(width, height);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    testCases = SanityTest.getSanityTestCases();
    control = new Control(testCases);
    run(control, 1000, 800);

}
```

My issue is setResult is not working. I am not sure why. Can anybody help? Thanks!

```
public void setResult(final String text, final String path)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            results.get(path).setText(text);
        }
    });
    control.getContentPane().validate();
}
}
```

Comment: Try placing the call to `control.getContentPane().validate()` (or just `control.validate()` which does the same thing) inside the runnable rather than outside of it. Currently, your pane is probably validated before the text is set, due to running the two calls on separate threads.

Comment: I would be extremely careful with the use of static, this can lead to more issues then it can sometimes solve...

Comment: I say just post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for faster help

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is at the `control.getContentPane().validate();` Try adding `control.repaint();` instead.